Drugs@FDA Dataset is not consistent with FDA?
Just attempted to search for drugs that were previously existing on the (Open FDA API for Drugs)[https://open.fda.gov/apis/drug/drugsfda/download/]  -
Drugs@FDA [/drug/drugsfda]
This endpoint's data may be downloaded in zipped JSON files. Records are represented in the same format as API calls to this endpoint. Each update to the data in this endpoint could change old records. You need to download all the files to ensure you have a complete and up-to-date dataset, not just the newest files. For more information about openFDA downloads, see the API basics.

There are 1 files, last updated on 2024-07-16.

As you can see it's been updated today on July 16th, 2024, but there's inconsistencies
With the accessdata website [https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm]
Eylea HD is nonexistent in the API but available in the website, Beovu as well.
Is this discrepancy a gbug?
Thanks!

Thank you for your question.
Accessdata and openFDA have different data release schedules, and as such are not always synchronized.
